# magento manage customer is not working in backend

Tags: magento

when i click on the magneto customers->manage customers the page was open and display the present customers in the store. when i want to edit one of the customer in the list the edit page is not displayed it display the message as"There has been an error processing your requestException printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 952761400"
please help me to rectify the error.

Comment: Check the folder `var/report`. There should be a file with the number 952761400 and if you open it, you see the full error.

Comment: thanks for your valuable information  but, i cant understand which the actual error lot of errors listing in that file..

Comment: yes i found that "Cannot load configuration for payment method" error can you please tell me how to fix that error..

Comment: that file is giving a full stack trace of the error, the top line will give you the part that actually caused the error. If you edit your post with that error we might be able to point you in the right direction. Also if your local or on a dev server you can turn error reports on by renaming /errors/local.xml.sample to just /errors/local.xml this will print those errors to screen. Just remember to disable it again before you go live.

Comment: Thanks Alan the error is a:5:{i:0;s:67:"Cannot load configuration for payment method "ecompayment_standard"";i:1;s:4072:"#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Helper\Data.php(48): Mage::throwException('Cannot load con...')

Comment: I repeat my problem FYI when i want to edit the customers by clicking on the customer name listing in the backend customers->manage customers the error comes like "There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1751286181 " can you please tell me how to fix that problem..

Comment: anyone who knows the solution please respond

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your payment module for ecompay. Check the settings in admin-system-configuration-payment methods. Make sure that the fields are filled in as per the requirements of the payment gateway.

Re-open your order, if it still will not open, disable the ecompay module. Go to admin-system-configuration-advanced, look for ecompay and disable. See if the orders open.

If this will not allow you to look at an order, place a test order with a different payment method, e.g. cheque. You may need to enable this module first.

Now open your test order. If this opens then you know the problem is with your ecompay gateway. Raise a support ticket with the people that wrote that module. If you get no response then go for a different payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Running this in the command line tool might solve your problem:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Don't forgot to set the file permission:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 <magento path>/app/etc
sudo chmod -R 777 <magento path>/var
sudo chmod -R 777 <magento path>/pub/media
sudo chmod -R 777 <magento path>/pub/static
```

Reference from:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3464#issuecomment-194800430